# Given $f :(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a monotone increasing function bounded above, show that $\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)$ exists

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $f :(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a monotone increasing function bounded above. Show that $\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)$ exists.

Okay, so what I've done is shown below. Apparently it's not enough because I've just shown that $f(x_n)$ converges. Could anyone give any hints as to how I can complete the proof?

Let $x_n=b-\dfrac{1}{n},n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then since $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},x_n<b$ and $x_{n+1}=b-\dfrac{1}{n+1}>b-\dfrac{1}{n}=x_n$, $x_n$ is monotone **increasing** and bounded above. Thus, by the Monotone Convergence Theorem, it has a limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=b^-$. Assume that $f :(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is monotone increasing and bounded above by some $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $f(x)$ is monotone increasing, we know that $f(x_n)<L \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. But here I'm stuck. How do I show precisely that the given limit exists?

Comment: Return to definition. Note that for any $x$ that is close enough to $b$, $\boldsymbol {x_{n} \leqslant x \leqslant x_{n+1} }$ for some $n \in \Bbb N^*$.

Comment: don't you mean that $f$ is a function, not a sequence? (Its domain is $(a,b)$, not $\Bbb N$.)

Comment: the notation $f :(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ implies that $f$ is defined for every $x\in(a,b)$, and this is a function, not a sequence. You could consider a sequence $x_n\in(a,b)$ and discuss $f(x_n)$ but that is another matter. That does not make $f$ a sequence.

Comment: @Mirko, could you provide some more hints as to how I could complete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application of *some* sequence.

Let $x_n = b -1/n$. Then $x _n \to b^-$. Since $f$ is increasing and bounded above, so is the sequence $(f(x_n))_1^\infty$. Therefore  it converges. Let the limit be $A$. By definition, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $N \in \Bbb N^*$ s.t. $\vert f(x_n) - A\vert < \varepsilon$ whenever $n \geqslant N$. Therefore for $\underline {\delta = b - x_N}$, whenever $\underline{x_N = b -\delta < x < b}$, there is an $M \in \Bbb N^*$ that $M \geqslant N$ and $x_M \leqslant x \leqslant x_{M+1}$. Then by monotonicity, $f(x_M) \leqslant f(x) \leqslant f(x_{M+1})$, and 
$$
\underline {- \varepsilon <}\ f(x_M) - A \leqslant \underline {f(x) - A} \leqslant f(x_{M+1}) - A\ \underline { < \varepsilon}\ , 
$$
i.e.
$$
\lim_{ x \to b^-} f(x) = A. 
$$

Comment: @Mirko Right, thanks!

Comment: @xbhwhat if $x_1 \not\in (a,b)$. Then wouldn't $f(x_n)$ be undefined?

Comment: @fordjones Then just discard those terms which are outside of $(a,b)$. Would not cause much problem.

Comment: can we just use this to show that if $a<c<b$, then $lim_{x\to c^-} f(x)$ and $lim_{x\to c^+} f(x)$ both exist?

Comment: @fordjones What do you mean by "this"? My proof? Sure, the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is bounded above, the set $f(a,b)=\{f(c):a<c<b\}$ must have a least upper bound $u$. We will show that $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=u$.

Take any $\varepsilon>0$. Since $u$ is a least upper bound, we have that 
$u-\varepsilon$ is no longer an upper bound, and hence there is some $c<b$ with 
$f(c)>u-\varepsilon$. Let $\delta=b-c$. Then if $x<b$ and $b-x<\delta$ we have that 
$c<x<b$ and by monotonicity $u-\varepsilon<f(c)\le f(x)\le u$.

Edit. Here is an attempt to incorporate/edit what the OP had, together with a hint by @xbh, and try to use sequences. So the sequence $x_n=b-\frac1n$ is monotone increasing (not decreasing) and converges to $b$ (since $\frac1n\to0$). The sequence $f(x_n)$ is also monotone increasing (since $f$ is monotone increasing, and $x_n$ are monotone increasing) and since $f(x_n)$ is bounded above, it must have a limit $L$, that is $f(x_n)\to L$, monotonically increasing, as $n\to\infty$. (We did just use the Monotone Convergence Theorem.)

It remains to show that $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=L$. Take any $\varepsilon>0$. There is $N$ big enough such that $f(x_n)>L-\varepsilon$ whenever $n>N$. 
Let $\delta=\frac1{N+1}$. At this point I do not see what is the virtue of using a sequence, instead of $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit, at any rate take $x$ with $b-x<\delta$, so then $x>b-\delta=x_{N+1}$, so $L-\varepsilon<f(x_{N+1})\le f(x)\le L$.

One may wish to involve sequences even more, and prove that for every sequence $y_k\to b^-$ (not necessarily increasing) we have that $f(y_k)\to L$ as $k\to\infty$. There will be $K$ large enough such that for all $k>K$ we have that $y_k>x_{N+1}$, so $L-\varepsilon<f(x_{N+1})\le f(y_k)\le L$.

Perhaps there are some variations of these ideas, and one can present a proof in slightly different forms.

Comment: @fordjones Then take mine to try.

Comment: @fordjones If you don't use the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of limit, then the definition involving sequences says that the $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exists if there is some number $L$ such that for *every* sequence $x_n\to b^-$ we have $f(x_n)\to L$. So I do not understand why the hint says use *some* sequence. Let again $u$ be the least upper bound of $f(a,b)$ and take any sequence $x_n\to b^-$. Take any $\varepsilon>0$. Well, I don't know, just stick a sequence in front of my answer and pretend you used it.

Comment: Have look at my hint. Is that  something implies the usage of "some" sequence?

Comment: @xbh the $f(x)\le L$ inequality in my edit needs more justification. That is done in your answer, using $f(x)\le f(x_{M+1})\le L$. For that matter one need not squeeze $x$ precisely in between $x_M$ and $x_{M+1}$ (though this is very natural to do). One could alternatively say that there is $J\ge N$ (as in your answer) with $x_N\le x\le x_J$ so then $A-\varepsilon<f(x_N)\le f(x)\le f(x_J)\le A$ (where $A=\lim_n\,f(x_n)$ in your answer). (Voting up, as I missed the detail that this extra justification is needed, so it was pointed out to me.)